# Rails - creating place with weekdays in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a model for a Place

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :open_days, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and a model for OpenDay:

```
class OpenDay < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :place
end
```

I want to be able to create a record of this place (what I have now is simple textfields) with day of the weeks (and hours) that the place is opened at.

**My current form:**

```
<%= form_for(@place) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label(:name) %>
    <%= f.text_field(:name, placeholder: "Place's name", class: "form-control") %>
    <%= f.label(:street) %>
    <%= f.text_field(:street, placeholder: "Street", class: "form-control") %>
    <%= f.fields_for :open_days do |open_day| %>
      <%= open_day.text_field :day %>
    <% end %>
    ....
<% end %>
```

**My new controller**

```
def new
    @place = Place.new
    7.times do
        @place.open_days.build
    end
end
```

I decided to go with a table (code below) but I have absolutely no idea how to create a form for another model inside my existing form for @place. And what's more to be able to save multiple records using this form. Searched through SO but came with noting.

**EDIT**

I somehow was able to do is, but now there is this problem:

```
....
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Open?</th>
      <%= f.fields_for :open_days do |o_day| %>
        <td><%= o_day.text_field :day, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>From:</th>
      <%= f.fields_for :open_days do |o_day| %>
        <td><%= o_day.text_field :from_time, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>To:</th>
      <%= f.fields_for :open_days do |o_day| %>
        <td><%= o_day.text_field :to_time, class: "form-control" %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

First table row is populated with input with names like

```
name="place[open_days_attributes][0][day]"
name="place[open_days_attributes][1][day]"
name="place[open_days_attributes][2][day]"
name="place[open_days_attributes][3][day]"
name="place[open_days_attributes][4][day]"
name="place[open_days_attributes][5][day]"
name="place[open_days_attributes][6][day]"
```

I would expect the next row to start also from 0 to be like this:

```
name="place[open_days_attributes][0][from_time]
```

but instead it is like this:

```
name="place[open_days_attributes][7][from_time]
```

How to change it to be iterating from 0 again?

Comment: Read the [guide on nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms). Come back if you have more questions.

Comment: I updated the question. I mean, I do not get how to be able to create multiple (e.g) text_fields? Should I somehow iterate through something?

Comment: I edited the question - some weird problem occured

Answer (score 0):

you should use nested attributes and form_for#fields_for

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html
  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for